# Parse JSON file, order by ID and return values with largest ID

Tags: python, json

JSON file:https://1drv.ms/u/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJpFPnbeAexYPwYu9Q

i used this code to get all lines from whole file (with error `KeyError: 'job'`)

```
datapath = '1.json'

data = json.load(open(datapath))

for issue in data['executions']:
  if 'id' in issue:
       print issue['date-started']['date'], issue['date-ended']['date'], issue['status'], issue['job']['name'], issue['id']

2018-04-03T17:43:34Z 2018-04-03T17:43:38Z failed aa 126
2018-04-03T17:42:26Z 2018-04-03T17:42:31Z succeeded test 125
2018-04-03T17:41:29Z 2018-04-03T17:41:37Z succeeded aa 124
2018-04-02T21:10:22Z 2018-04-02T21:10:28Z succeeded aa 123
2018-04-02T21:09:27Z 2018-04-02T21:09:33Z failed aa 122
2018-03-30T18:20:44Z 2018-03-30T18:20:47Z succeeded aa 121
2018-03-30T17:52:54Z 2018-03-30T17:52:57Z succeeded aa 120
2018-03-30T17:31:47Z 2018-03-30T17:31:49Z succeeded aa 119
2018-03-30T17:28:15Z 2018-03-30T17:28:17Z failed aa 118
2018-03-26T19:26:08Z 2018-03-26T19:26:13Z succeeded test 117
2018-03-26T19:24:29Z 2018-03-26T19:24:33Z succeeded test 116
2018-03-26T19:23:51Z 2018-03-26T19:23:53Z failed test 115
2018-03-26T19:21:57Z 2018-03-26T19:22:00Z succeeded
```

it returned all values + one without job (that's why i get above error)

Need to get values with highest job ID - `issue['id']`, last value in my "select" statement-last column in output

desired output:

```
2018-04-03T17:43:34Z 2018-04-03T17:43:38Z failed aa 126
```

need this because Zabbix can't handle multiple outputs so want to "feed" it with most current job (specified by issue['id'] )

`jq` has order by and pipe it to `.[0]`, don't know if something exists for python

Comment: Define "highest"

Comment: highest issue['id'], last value in my "select" , this is line i want to get:2018-04-03T17:43:34Z 2018-04-03T17:43:38Z failed aa 126

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the `KeyError`, change this line:

`if 'id' in issue:`

...to check for the key's presence:

`if 'id' in issue and 'job' in issue:`

Note that you only need to do this if you are accessing the `job` key (you are in printing, but don't need that to check the highest ID).

To get the highest ID:

```
max_id = 0
for issue in data['executions']:
    if 'id' in issue and issue['id'] > max_id:
        max_id = issue['id']
```

To do this in one line using List Comprehension:

`max_id = max([i.get('id',0) for i in data['executions']])`

*This shows the highest issue id, not the highest issue job id since there is no clear description of how to rank these in your question

Comment: it works !! Jacob, now how to filter and get only line with highest ID ?

Comment: He wants `issue['job']['id']`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues in the file have a `job` property, some don't. You need to check for that before trying to use it, or use `setdefault` to provide a default value.

```
issue.setdefault('job', {'name': 'noname', 'id': -1});
print issue['date-started']['date'], issue['date-ended']['date'], issue['status'], issue['job']['name'], issue['id']
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, i need to get values i specified only for job with highest ID, i need script for Job monitor iz zabbix, that's why i need to get latest job, it's id,name,status, start and end date

Comment: There's nothing in your question that tries to get the highest ID. Do you mean `issue['id']` or `issue['job']['id']`?

Comment: issue['job']['id'] (in this case it's 126)

Comment: I've added a placeholder `id` to the `setdefault` call.